# how to get random number between 0 and 1

Tags: javascript, math

i tried a few ways to get a random number from 1 to 10 and all return undefined or NaN why ?
here is what i tried

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random * 10)

function getNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random * 10);
}
var num2 = getNum();
console.log('num = ' + num + 'num2 = ' + num2);
```

both dosn't give a number when logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually *invoke* `Math.random` if you intend for it to generate the random number (ie `Math.random()`)

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

function getNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
var num2 = getNum();
console.log('num = ' + num + 'num2 = ' + num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random` is a method, not a property, so you need to call it as `Math.random()`.  You are also missing a semicolon after your first line.

Comment: Semicolons are optional in JS. I mostly don't type them. Upvoted nonetheless

Comment: I hesitate to upvote this only because the statement "*You are also missing a semicolon...*" isn't particularly relevant nor true because of [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

Comment: @JeremyThille - It may be worth clarifying your comment for future visitors to this answer (while you still can) to reflect that semicolons are "optional" only under certain criteria ([relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)). There are situations where the presence of a semicolon (or lackthereof) will materially affect the interpretation of a given segment of JavaScript code.

Comment: your a life saver been staring at it for an hour

Comment: Yes I know, I pulled my hair out many times with a line finishing with `()` and the next starting with a `[` :) Semicolons are indeed _mostly_ optional.

Comment: you dont need a ; semi colon between variables especily if you have them in 2 lines

Comment: You might not strictly "need" a semicolon in this particular circumstance because browsers will cover for you, but it is best practice, especially since there are circumstances where you will need a semicolon, and it is nice to have consistent nomenclature with those circumstances, instead of having and omitting semicolons at random.  There are also instances where your code might work but look ambiguous to other readers, who might not know your intentions.  jshint and jslint will also regard this as an error, and I think "use strict" picks it up as an error as well.

Comment: Additionally, when you are using a minifier, you will need to have the semicolons in there.  Some minifiers might insert them for you, maybe, but I would rather not leave it up to chance to let the minifier correctly interpret your code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @kloddant Math.random is method so you forgot the parentheses ().
So here's the snippet of how you can implement it

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10))   

function getNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10));
}
var num2 = getNum();
console.log('num = ' + num + 'num2 = ' + num2);
```